# QGIS Excluding One Variable from Labels

Tags: qgis, labeling, line

I am currently labelling a roads map and need help removing the labels for a specific "type" of road.

I apologies for my terminology but I am new to the program.

In my attributes table I have columns "ROAD_NAME" & "ROAD_TYPE" with the latter differentiating between whether the road is a Lane, Highway, Freeway, Street, etc. Some roads are labelled "UNNAMED" in both of these columns. On our other system these roads are present on the map but have no naming.

I currently have applied the rule - "ROAD_NAME || ' ' || ROAD_TYPE" and merged the lines, which has worked well for the other roads but has the UNNAMED roads labelled with "UNNAMED".

I would like the UNNAMED roads still visible on the map but I want the label to disappear.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Simply you can disable the labeling of 'UNNAMED' from `Layer Properties -> Labeling -> Rendering -> Show Label` under `Data defined` then `Edit`:

[image]

Write the following:

```
"ROAD_TYPE" != 'UNNAMED'
```

All the labels of road type that is unnamed will be disabled.

Answer (score 5):

you can add an if clause to your label statement:

```
if("ROAD_NAME"='UNNAMED','',"ROAD_NAME" || ' ' || "ROAD_TYPE")
```

or alternativly use rule based labeling, where your rule would be:

```
"ROAD_NAME"<>'UNNAMED'
```